# How can i get xml data without XmlDataDocument

Tags: xml

I am following  an example .But visual studio says `XmlDataDocument` is outdated anymore.So how can i run this code without XmlDataDocument .

```
    public XmlElement GetUserDetails(string userName)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from Orders where ShipName like @name +'%'",conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",userName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    XmlDataDocument data=new XmlDataDocument(ds);
    XmlElement elemment=data.DocumentElement;
    return  elemment;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the XElement and XDocument types in the [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

using an extension method like this one makes the transition easy

```
public static XmlElement ToXmlElement(this XElement el)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(el.CreateReader());
    return doc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Then the last 3 lines of your method simply need to be replaced with.

```
var data=new XDocument(ds);
var element = data.Root;
return  element.ToXmlElement();
```

which can be shortened to just

```
return new XElement(ds).ToXmlElement();
```

The XElement type has many useful qualities. For example it can be queried by calling the Elements() extension method which returns an IEnumerable<XElement>.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: please can u you give me a link or  an example this is my second xml application